# CAn't connect to a local server (XAMPP) from HoloLens

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, xampp, hololens

I'm trying to build a connection between the HoloLens and XAMMP server.
when i test the app on unity, it works fine but it doesn't work on the device.

Ps: you can access the server when writing the IP address of the server In Microsoft Edge.

- Windows defender firewall is disabled
- Network capabilities are checked (publishing settings)
- XAMPP server is reconfigured to be accessible to all devices

what am I missing here ? how can I make this work ?

Comment: Hi there, could you share your code with us? Are you getting any exceptions/errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text playerDisplay;
    public Text score;
    public Button submit;
    public InputField nameField;
    public GameObject bb;
    public Text Error;

    public void CallLogIn()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Loginplayer());
    }

    IEnumerator Loginplayer()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("name", nameField.text);


        WWW www = new WWW("http://192.168.1.100/sqlconnect/test.php", form);
        yield return www;
        if (www.text[0] == '0')
        {

            DBManager.username = nameField.text;
            DBManager.score = int.Parse(www.text.Split('\t')[1]);

            playerDisplay.text = "player: " + DBManager.username;
            score.text = "score: " + DBManager.score;

            bb.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Error.text = "save failes. Error #" + www.error;
            bb.SetActive(false);
        }
        DBManager.logedOut();


    }
}
```

Comment: is this really supposed to be an answer or did you rather want to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55219983/edit) your question and insert it there??

Comment: No, it's not the answer.. it's the code i have used in my app. i should've insert it in the question, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this kind of issue as well. I tried to connect the HoloLens to different entities (MySQL DB, OPCUA Server) but it always fails on the HoloLens (working fine in the editor). Searching on google only revealed similar problems from other people, but no solutions.

So my solution is to use the WWW class to receive data from a HTML-Webserver that hosts plain text. This server (I used nodejs and python) executes the query to the database depending on the GET-request it receives from the HoloLens.